# Relationship between log-linear (e.g. Poisson) GLM and GLMM with random intercepts

Tags: glmm, generalized-estimating-equations

In their textbook "Analysis of Longitudinal data" Diggle et al. state (p. 137 in the second edition) that:

> In log-linear models for counted data, random effects and marginal parameters can be equivalent in important special cases. Consider the random effects model
> $$
> \log E(Y_{i, j} | U_i) = x'_{i, j}\beta^* + d'_{i, j} U_i 
> $$
> where $d_{i, j}$ is a vector forming a subset of the variables in $x_{i, j}$. The marginal expectation has the form:
> $$
> E(Y_{i, j}) = \int \exp(x'_{i, j} \beta^*) \exp(d_{i, j}' U_i) f(U_i) dU_i
> $$
> In the random intercept case with $d_{i, j} = 1$ note that $E(Y_{i, j} = \exp(x'_{i, j} \beta^* + v^2 / 2)$ so that the marginal expectation has the same exponential form apart from the an additive constant in the exponent. Hence, if we fit a marginal model which assumes that $E(Y_{i, j} = \exp(x'_{i, j} \beta)$ all of the parameters, except the intercept will have the same value and interpretation as in the random effects model

This equivalence is also described in [A Note on Fitting a Marginal Model to Mixed Effects Log-Linear Regression Data via GEE](https://www.jstor.org/stable/pdf/2533162.pdf?refreqid=excelsior%3A28246f7f87b85825e770c1c3181b1f2b&ab_segments=&origin=&acceptTC=1). (See 3. Special Cases (1))

However, this observation does not always appear to be true in practice! Consider the following R code:

```r
set.seed(801)

suppressPackageStartupMessages({
  library(lme4)
  library(gee)
  library(dplyr)
  library(tidyr)
})

n_levels <- 2
n_groups <- 2
n_obvs <- 100
mu_level <- c(0.2, 0.8)
group_sigma <- 0.5

data <- bind_cols(
  level = factor(rep(c("a", "b"), each = n_groups)),
  group = 1:(n_levels * n_groups)
) %>% 
  expand_grid(obv = seq_len(n_obvs)) %>% 
  mutate(
    mu_level = rep(mu_level, each = n_groups * n_obvs), 
    mu_group = rep(rnorm(n_levels * n_groups, 0, group_sigma), each = n_obvs),
    y = rpois(n_levels * n_groups * n_obvs, lambda = exp(mu_level + mu_group))
  )

# GLM
summary(glm(y ~ level, family = "poisson", data = data))
#> 
#> Call:
#> glm(formula = y ~ level, family = "poisson", data = data)
#> 
#> Deviance Residuals: 
#>     Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max  
#> -1.8000  -1.5460  -0.1836   0.6708   3.1230  
#> 
#> Coefficients:
#>             Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
#> (Intercept)  0.17815    0.06468   2.754 0.005886 ** 
#> levelb       0.30428    0.08527   3.569 0.000359 ***
#> ---
#> Signif. codes:  0 '***' 0.001 '**' 0.01 '*' 0.05 '.' 0.1 ' ' 1
#> 
#> (Dispersion parameter for poisson family taken to be 1)
#> 
#>     Null deviance: 506.62  on 399  degrees of freedom
#> Residual deviance: 493.74  on 398  degrees of freedom
#> AIC: 1223.2
#> 
#> Number of Fisher Scoring iterations: 5

# GLMM
summary(glmer(y ~ level + (1 | group), family = "poisson", data = data))
#> Generalized linear mixed model fit by maximum likelihood (Laplace
#>   Approximation) [glmerMod]
#>  Family: poisson  ( log )
#> Formula: y ~ level + (1 | group)
#>    Data: data
#> 
#>      AIC      BIC   logLik deviance df.resid 
#>   1216.6   1228.6   -605.3   1210.6      397 
#> 
#> Scaled residuals: 
#>     Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
#> -1.3828 -1.0636 -0.2291  0.6628  4.2308 
#> 
#> Random effects:
#>  Groups Name        Variance Std.Dev.
#>  group  (Intercept) 0.02377  0.1542  
#> Number of obs: 400, groups:  group, 4
#> 
#> Fixed effects:
#>             Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)
#> (Intercept)   0.1737     0.1268   1.370    0.171
#> levelb        0.2896     0.1765   1.641    0.101
#> 
#> Correlation of Fixed Effects:
#>        (Intr)
#> levelb -0.718

# GEE
gee(y ~ level, id = group, family = "poisson", data = data)
#> Beginning Cgee S-function, @(#) geeformula.q 4.13 98/01/27
#> running glm to get initial regression estimate
#> (Intercept)      levelb 
#>   0.1781462   0.3042800
#> 
#>  GEE:  GENERALIZED LINEAR MODELS FOR DEPENDENT DATA
#>  gee S-function, version 4.13 modified 98/01/27 (1998) 
#> 
#> Model:
#>  Link:                      Logarithm 
#>  Variance to Mean Relation: Poisson 
#>  Correlation Structure:     Independent 
#> 
#> Call:
#> gee(formula = y ~ level, id = group, data = data, family = "poisson")
#> 
#> Number of observations :  400 
#> 
#> Maximum cluster size   :  100 
#> 
#> 
#> Coefficients:
#> (Intercept)      levelb 
#>   0.1781462   0.3042800 
#> 
#> Estimated Scale Parameter:  1.121611
#> Number of Iterations:  1
#> 
#> Working Correlation[1:4,1:4]
#>      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
#> [1,]    1    0    0    0
#> [2,]    0    1    0    0
#> [3,]    0    0    1    0
#> [4,]    0    0    0    1
#> 
#> 
#> Returned Error Value:
#> [1] 0
```

<sup>Created on 2022-06-07 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

In this simulation (distilled from other empirical investigations) the GLMM and GLM parameters estimates are not the same! What have I missed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The marginal model (generalized estimating equations; GEE) and the mixed effects model (generalized linear mixed effects model; GLMM) are not equivalent because the *group* clusters in the GEE don't have the same structure as the *group* random effects in the GLMM.

First, let's introduce two encodings of the *group* variable. One encoding leads to equivalent Poisson GEE and GLMM; the other does not.

`group2` with two groups: Within each group half the samples are assigned to level *a* and the rest to level *b*.

```
xtabs(~ level + group2, data)
#>      group2
#> level   1   2
#>     a 100 100
#>     b 100 100
```

`group4` with four groups: Each group is assigned to one of two levels, *a* and *b*. This is your original encoding.

```
xtabs(~ level + group4, data)
#>      group4
#> level   1   2   3   4
#>     a 100 100   0   0
#>     b   0   0 100 100
```

The crux of the matter is that the two encodings result in different GLMMs for the same data, even if we use the same model formula *y ~ level + (1 | group)*. That is, the GLMM is not uniquely identified by the formula alone.

With the `group2` encoding, there are two clusters in the GEE and the marginal expectation is $\textrm{E}(Y_{ij}) = \beta_0 + \beta_1 \textrm{I\{level=b\}}$ where $\textrm{I\{level=b\}}$ is an indicator variable for the *b* level.

In the GLMM there are two random intercepts $U_i$ drawn for a normal distribution with mean 0. I don't write the full specification of the mixed effects model; the salient parts are given in Eq. (1).

\begin{aligned}
\textrm{(1)} \quad\quad
\log\operatorname{E}(Y_{ij}) = \beta_0 + \beta_1\textrm{I\{level=b\}} + U_i, \quad
\operatorname{E}(U_i) = 0
\end{aligned}

*Aside*: Two unique groups are too few to justify representing the *group* variable as a random effect. One rule of thumb is that a random-effect categorical variable has at least 5 categories. [Should I treat factor xxx as fixed or random?](https://bbolker.github.io/mixedmodels-misc/glmmFAQ.html#should-i-treat-factor-xxx-as-fixed-or-random)

With the `group4` encoding, very little changes in the GEE formulation: the marginal expectation is $\textrm{E}(Y_{ij}) = \beta_0 + \beta_1\textrm{I\{level=b\}}$ but there are four clusters instead of two.

On the other hand, in the GLMM there are four random intercepts $U_i$, one for each group, in a multi-level hierarchy. Think of the hierarchy as a model with two components: a linear regression for the random effects $U_i$ (group component) and a Poisson regression for the observed counts $Y_{ij}$ given the group effects (individual component). This hierarchy is described in Eq. (2).

\begin{aligned}
\textrm{(2)} \quad\quad\quad
\log\operatorname{E}(Y_{ij}) = U_i, \quad
\operatorname{E}(U_i) = \beta_0 + \beta_1\textrm{I\{level=b\}}
\end{aligned}

*Intuition*: To understand the hierarchical structure, consider that with the `group4` encoding all items in the same group also have the same level (and the same expected value). So we cannot estimate the difference between levels *a* and *b* by comparing items in the same group. We have two compare groups instead. This makes the *level* variable a group predictor, not an individual predictor.

*Aside*: The terms "level" and "group" are often used to describe hierarchical model structure; in the future consider using "safe" terms in examples such as *X1* and *X2*.

Mathematically, the formulation in Eq. (2) doesn't satisfy the assumption that $\mathbf{d}_{ij}$ is a subset of the variables in $\mathbf{x}_{ij}$. In this case, $\mathbf{d}$ is the categorical variable which indicates which level each group belongs to and $\mathbf{x}$ is an empty set because there are no individual predictors in $\log\operatorname{E}(Y_{ij}) = U_i$.

Now that we understand the structure of the marginal model (GEE) and the mixed effects model (GLMM) under the two different encodings of the *level* variable, let's fit the models and look at the fixed-effects estimates.

As expected, with the `group2` encoding the GLMM has the same estimate and interpretation of `(levelb)` — that's the $\beta_1$ in the formulas — as the GEE.

```r
# GLMM with 4 random intercepts
tidy(glmer(y ~ level + (1 | group4), family = poisson, data = data))
#>   effect   group  term            estimate std.error statistic p.value
#>   <chr>    <chr>  <chr>              <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>   <dbl>
#> 1 fixed    <NA>   (Intercept)        0.174     0.127      1.37   0.171
#> 2 fixed    <NA>   levelb             0.290     0.177      1.64   0.101

# GLMM with 2 random intercepts
tidy(glmer(y ~ level + (1 | group2), family = poisson, data = data))
#>   effect   group  term            estimate std.error statistic   p.value
#> 1 fixed    <NA>   (Intercept)       0.175     0.0870      2.01  0.0445  
#> 2 fixed    <NA>   levelb            0.304     0.0852      3.57  0.000357

# NB. `gee` and `geepack` assume that the data is sorted so that
# observations on each cluster appear as contiguous rows in data.

# GEE with 4 clusters
tidy(geeglm(y ~ level, id = group4, family = poisson, data = data %>% arrange(group4)))
#>   term        estimate std.error statistic  p.value
#> 1 (Intercept)    0.178    0.0503     12.5  0.000397
#> 2 levelb         0.304    0.169       3.24 0.0720

# GEE with 2 clusters
tidy(geeglm(y ~ level, id = group2, family = poisson, data = data %>% arrange(group2)))
#>   term        estimate std.error statistic  p.value
#> 1 (Intercept)    0.178    0.0503     12.5  0.000397
#> 2 levelb         0.304    0.212       2.06 0.151
```

*References*

Hierarchical regression (aka regression with random intercepts and/or slopes) is an advanced topic. You can learn more in Part 2A of Gelman and Hill, *Data Analysis Using Regression and Multilevel/Hierarchical Models*. Cambridge University Press, 2007.

Comment: Thanks for that answer @dipetkov One further point of confusion: where does the requirement for $\mathbf{d_{i, j}}$  to be a subset  of $\mathbf{x_{i, j}}$ enter into the proof? In both the examples you give I would expect $d_{i, j} = 1$ so the marginal expectation $E(Y_{i, j})$ would be the same.

Comment: I've updated my answer to add more details, or at least, intuition about how the coding of the *level* variable determines the structure of the GEE and the LMM. This is not exactly a proof but hopefully it's still a useful explanation that stand on its own apart from the code.

Comment: Thanks for that clarification @dipetkov! One final detail I don't understand: how can $\mathbf{d}$ be the level variable in the 4 groups model? Given the variable is binary, wouldn't that imply only groups with level == 1 would have a random effect?

Comment: No, all groups have random effects: there are four random effects $U_i$, one for each group. Two $U_i$s have expectation $E\{\beta_0\}$ and two $U_i$s have expectation $E\{\beta_0 + \beta_1\}$. So take a look at Eq 2. and think what is $x$ in the formula for $E\{Y_{ij}\}$ and what is $d$ in the formula for $E\{U_i\}$.

Comment: I must admit that I am still confused! In my mind we have $U_i \sim N(0, \sigma^2)$ and then we multiply this by the random effect coefficients $d_{i, j}$ in the first formula in the question. So I don't understand how you can think about $d$ as controlling $E(U_i)$ at all...

Comment: There are two gaps in your understanding: 1. Random effects are not always $N(0, \sigma^2)$ random variables. In your LMM the random effects are $U_i \sim N(\beta_0 + \beta_1\textrm{I\{level=b\}}, \sigma^2)$. That is, your LMM has hierarchical structure that is not represented in the GEE. Hence the LMM and GEE are not equivalent.

Comment: 2. In your simulation both *level* and *group* are categorical variables. It's not helpful to think of categorical variables are numerical variables which multiply the random effects. This leads you to the incorrect statement that only groups with level == 1 have a random effect. No. Each group has its own random effect.

Comment: I have now accepted your answer, thanks for your insight into the hierarchical structure of the problem. I still remain unconvinced about the exceptions of the random effects however. If you want I think it would be clarifying for you to include the explicit mathematical form (in the format of the first equation in the quote in the question) of the group4 encoding model. But I am happy to accept the answer without that final detail.

Comment: Thank you for accepting the answer. I've already written the formula for $\log E(Y_{ij})$ -- the way I understood to be correct at least. However, it's clear that you are not convinced it's the right formula. So I encourage you to post a follow-up question. It's the best way to get other people's responses.